# 404 Error when trying to execute web service

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I have a simple web service I have created. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 .NET 4.5.

Here is the service contract:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace GEMS.Core.WCFService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMenuService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void AddMenuItem(string menuId, string parentId, string title, string description, string url);
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateMenuItem(string menuId, string parentId, string title, string description, string url);
        [OperationContract]
        void DeleteMenuItem(string menuId);
        [OperationContract]
        MenuEntry[] GetAllMenuItems();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class MenuEntry
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string MenuId { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ParentId { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Url { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

The relevant portion of the app.config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="GEMS.Core.WCFService.MenuService">
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8020/GEMS.Core.WCFService/MenuService/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GEMS.Core.WCFService.IMenuService" >
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I publish it to my IIS server (local to my box).

In the client app, I create a service reference. When I click Discover, it finds:

```
http://localhost:8020/GEMS.Core.WCFService/MenuService/mex
```

When I run my client, however, I get the following message:

```
There was no endpoint listening at:
http://localhost:8020/GEMS.Core.WCFService/MenuService/ that could
accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

The inner exception merely says that it got a 404 error from the web server.

The client's .config file has the following auto-generated xml:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMenuService" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8020/GEMS.Core.WCFService/MenuService/"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMenuService"
      contract="WCF_MenuService.IMenuService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMenuService" />
  </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

I've been going around in circles for hours and can't figure out what I've got glitched up, but surely I've done somethign wrong.

Not sure that it matters, but the client is an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: Can you try browsing to the service itself in a webbrowser without using the client. If you do not get to see the usual WCF webpage, you will most likely need to turn on WCF HTTP Activation (and some other stuff) in the windows features.

Comment: There's definitely some weird stuff going on in several areas. First of all, the Discovery is getting the wrong URL. The actual URL is: localhost/GEMS.Core.WCFService.MenuService.svc 
Futhermore when I generate the service reference, it doesn't create the class. If, however, I create a simple console app and have it create the service reference, that works fine (given the proper URL above). I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like Newtonsoft.json might be causing some fishiness.

Comment: Still trying to get everything working, but so far, the first step was to create the service client in another app and then copy it over to my real app and change the namespace references. Looking like it may be a VS.NET issue.

Comment: Rikkos, if I use the correct url (and sorry, I had that wrong in that last comment. It's localhost:8020/... and the http:// before it, of course) But yes, I can browse to it. If I do it with ?wsdl it gives me the correct wsdl.

Comment: There are definitely some issues with the class generation when you add a service reference. Here is the solution that worked for me. When you add a service reference, click on the 'Advanced...' button in the 'Add service reference' - window, and then disable 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'. Then your classes should be generated.

Comment: Okay, I've confirmed that part of the problem is that Newtonsoft.json.dll (which is referenced by default in ASP.NET MVC 4 projects) causes the the Add Service Reference to fail to generate the code in Reference.cs, so you end up with Reference.cs having the comment header and nothing else. So this, I would imagine, is a VS.NET bug. If I remove the Newtonsoft.json reference, Reference.cs generates properly.

Comment: Interesting, your solution works as well (and allows the Newtonsoft.json reference to remain. Go ahead and post that and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pete explained Newtonsoft.json.dll causes client to not generate the service code. You can either delete the dll and then add the service reference again.

Or you can do try following solution that worked for me. When you add a service reference,

1. Click on the 'Advanced...' button in the 'Add service reference' - window
2. Disable 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'.

Then your classes should be generated.