# Strange issue when adding a service reference to a project that has the JSON.NET library referenced

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, wcf, json.net, service-reference

The project is your standard run-of-the-mill [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 3 application that communicates with an in house WCF service. Our ASP.NET MVC application references a few external libraries, including the popular JSON.NET library.

The issue only occurs when the JSON.NET library is a reference in a project. I tried recreating this issue with a WebForms and a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project, and the same thing happens.

When adding a service reference to our WCF service, and JSON.NET is a reference in our project, it builds the service reference like this:

With JSON.NET referenced in the project - notice the Request/Response Classes and the weird properties like Id1 and IdSpecified

[image: With JSON.NET]

But removing the reference to JSON.NET and updating the service reference builds it the way we want, like this:

Without JSON.NET referenced in the project

[image: Without JSON.NET]

...

What in the world would cause this? JSON.NET is not referenced in the WCF project, so I highly doubt that there could be some sort of mix up there.

Some information that may help:

- Tried checking various options in the Add Service Reference dialog such as *"Reuse types in referenced assemblies"* - but the same thing happens
- Visual Studio 2010
- WCF service uses Entity Framework for data access

Comment: I've seen a similiar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918062/404-error-when-trying-to-execute-web-service/12921319). If you use Newtonsoft.json.dll can you remove and add the webservice properly? Also can you browse to the webservice and find the wsdl?

Comment: Yes, removing the reference to JSON.NET and then adding the service reference works correctly. And yes, the wsdl is there like is should be.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a service reference, WCF by default will reuse the classes from your assemblies that match the ones that will be generated otherwise.

This happens because, for example, you might develop both the service and the client and you might want to have a class library with all the classes referenced in both projects. This also makes sure that .NET default types (like arrays, lists, DateTime) are used.

You can change this default behavior like this:

1. Click the *Advanced* button after you selected "Add service reference"
2. Select "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies"
3. Check all the assemblies, except the ones that you don't want to
   use

Note that if you don't check the system assemblies, you will get a new type generated in the proxy file for every .NET type (like arrays, lists) as well.